# Execute external script in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to integrate the podigee podcast player (https://github.com/podigee/podigee-podcast-player) on my Gatsby/react (16.8.6) site.

Loading the external script in my in `componentDidMount()` works fine. Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const PlayerConfiguration = {
      episode: {
        media: {
          https: "https://testing.podigee.io/1-neue-episode.mp3",
          m4a: "https://testing.podigee.io/1-neue-episode.m4a",
          ogg: "https://testing.podigee.io/1-neue-episode.ogg",
          mp3: "https://testing.podigee.io/1-neue-episode.mp3",
          opus: "https://testing.podigee.io/1-neue-episode.opus"
        },
        title: "Neue Episode"
      }
    };

    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src =
      "https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js";
    script.setAttribute("data-configuration", { PlayerConfiguration });
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="player">
          <h2>Playercomponent</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**However, the script never runs and creates an iframe as it is supposed to. How do I actually execute the script once it is loaded? It is one big IIFE so shouldn't it run by itself?**

```
!function t(e, i, n) {
function r(s, a) {
    if (!i[s]) {...
```

The full script can be found here: "https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js"

Example on codesandox: https://codesandbox.io/s/podigee-script-tag-in-react-87ud8?fontsize=14

If some could point me in the right direction I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Podigee support was kind enough to help me out and provide an example. So to answer my own question for anyone struggling with something like this:
The key takeaway was that the configuration should be JSON and not passed as an object in react.

```
return JSON.stringify({
    episode: { 
        media: {
            mp3: "..."
        }
    }
});
```

A working example can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/podigee-player-in-react-87ud8

Answer (score 0):

Look into React Load Script - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script

```
import Script from 'react-load-script'

...

render() {
  return (
    <Script
      url="https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js"
      onCreate={this.handleScriptCreate.bind(this)}
      onError={this.handleScriptError.bind(this)}
      onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad.bind(this)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem: The script gets loaded as before but I still dont know how to run the script itself. I probably have to call a function in `handleScriptLoad` but which and how? Thanks!

You can see the code sandbox for this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/podigee-script-tag-in-react-zp06j?fontsize=14

Comment: try -  componentWillMount() {
    window.functiontocallinyourscript();
  }

Comment: Which function do I have to call in my script? I tried `componentWillMount() { window.t(); }` (t() is the first function in the script) but that didn't work.. Here ist the direct link to the script: https://cdn.podigee.com/podcast-player/javascripts/podigee-podcast-player.js Thank you for your help!

Comment: The podigee script uses an IIFE. Could that be the problem?